# What is the difference between NoSetter and ReadOnly?

Tags: nhibernate, readonly

What is the difference between NoSetter and ReadOnly?

NHibernate defines the following enum:

```
namespace NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode
{
    public enum Accessor
    {
        Property = 0,
        Field = 1,
        NoSetter = 2,
        ReadOnly = 3,
        None = 4,
    }
}
```

The docs say this about NoSetter, but fail to mention ReadOnly:

*NHibernate will access the field directly when setting the value and will use the Property when getting the value. This can be used when a property only exposes a get accessor because the consumers of your API can't change the value directly. A naming strategy is required because NHibernate uses the value of the name attribute as the property name and needs to be told what the name of the field is.*

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read only property accessor for persisting calculated properties that don't provide a set method or a backing field.
The calculated value can then be used for querying purposes but it is not read back into the domain.

Source: [link](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1621)